# Ubuntu for Android on the ASUS Transformer Prime

Tags: asus, x11, ubuntu-for-android

I would like to use Ubuntu on my Transformer Prime in parallel with Android (not as a dual booting solution, I want to be able to switch between them instantaniously).

I am aware of the traditional chrooting/VNC solution but I heard that it performs very poorly so I would like to use Ubuntu For Android (UFA) which has been announced recently by Canonical. That looks like a polished, highly integrated solution for Android devices.

The Prime would be the ideal device for Ubuntu For Android since it has a powerful processor (Tegra3) capable of running a lot of processes in parallel on its 4 cores.

Does anyone know if Canonical or anybody else is working on supporting UFA on the ASUS Transformer Prime?

As far as I understand, the X11 driver is available for Tegra3 so, the biggest hurdle may be easily overcome.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand the Ubuntu For Android (UFA) is not to provide two operating system in android device which can be used simultaneously. Ubuntu is activated only when you connect a keyboard,mouse and display and at that moment you cannot use the device rather your device works as CPU for Ubuntu with access to android contacts and other things.

And as far as I know, it will be integrated and shipped by the device manufacturer. So you can get it only on the new devices preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

It's early days yet for Ubuntu for Android so you would have to go with the dualboot over at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1603921).